# How to write a program for continue; using C

Tags: c, continue

How to execute the code without actually using the continue statement.
In other words, **How can I write a program for continue; statement** without using "continue;" (definition for continue;).

Thanks in advance

```
int a = 10;
while(a < 20){
  if(a == 15){
    a = a+1;
    continue;   
  }
  print ("%d", a);
  a++;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean that you want a code with the same behavior without using a continue statement?

Comment: Since the code for `a == 15` does exactly the same thing to `a` (i.e. increments it), but doesn't print it,  `while (a < 20) {if (a != 15) print("%d", a");  ++a;}` will do it.

Comment: To emulate `continue`, you could use `goto` (not recommended) or a properly scoped `if else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the `else` statement here with proper scope emulates what a continue statement would do (which is to skip to the end of the while loop).  I have purposely left the rest of your code unchanged.

```
int a = 10;
while(a < 20){
  if(a == 15){
    a = a+1;
//    continue;   
  } else {
    print ("%d", a);
    a++;
  }
}
```

or if you want to invoke the wrath of the C gods

```
int a = 10;
while(a < 20){
  if(a == 15){
    a = a+1;
//    continue;   
    goto next;  // Really - don't do this...
  }
  print ("%d", a);
  a++;
next:
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`continue` has no effect at all in your code.
And your print function should be `printf`.

The only number not being printed is 15.
So you can do this:

```
while(a < 20) {
     if(a != 15) printf("%d", a);
     a++; 
}
```

Comment: "`continue` has no effect at all in your code" false. It most definitely has an effect.

Comment: While I didn't downvote, I'm unclear how both "continue has no effect" and "15 doesn't print" statements can be true.

Comment: I won't down vote - but does this answer the real question of "What really is the `continue` doing so that I understand it well enough to replace it?"  Yes, your code is simpler and executes how OP wants his code to run, but does it demonstrate a simple replacement for continue?

Comment: This answer solves the computational problem, but doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: In this case, the observable behavior of the code just happens to be the same both with and without the `continue`, but the way you said it is misleading and makes it seems like it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @FeiXiang I totally agree; thanks for understanding my point.
I totally recognize its importance and how it comes handy and helpful.
But as we said, with or without it, it is the same in this case!